# Spring SerializingHttpMessageConverter - GZIPResponseStream error

Tags: spring

In org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write() is a call to

```
    writeInternal(t, outputMessage);
    outputMessage.getBody().flush();
```

in the Implementation in SerializingHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal() is a call to

```
    objectStream.flush();
    objectStream.close();
```

I guess this is the Reaseon for my Error in GZIPResponseStream.flush():

```
public void flush() throws IOException {
    if(this.closedFlag) {
        throw new IOException("Cannot flush a closed output stream");
```

Producing the Message

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/04/09 14:05:06.673 | SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcherServlet threw exception
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/04/09 14:05:06.673 | java.io.IOException: Cannot flush a closed output stream
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/04/09 14:05:06.673 |   at de.hybris.platform.util.GZIPResponseStream.flush(GZIPResponseStream.java:70)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/04/09 14:05:06.673 |   at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:182)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2016/04/09 14:05:06.673 |   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.writeWithMessageConverters(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:975)
```

is there an Error in the Framework, or do I miss someting. Is there another reaseon for this error? (AND PROB. A FIX?)